# Quick Edit Duplicate Field Error SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, content-type, site-column, uls, quick-edit

I have a `Pages` library in which there are two `Site Content types`: `Normal Pages` & `Seminar Pages`.

Both `content types` contains similar fields except some. Now I have one `Site Column` which is inside both of the `content type`, that field is `Page Title` (custom one).

I have more than 300 items in my current `Pages` library. 
When I try to update the some of the item fields from the `Quick Edit` view, it is not updating this `Page Title` field value.

Also it is not giving any `unexpected` error. I have checked the ULS logs it has duplicate entry of this `Page Title` field.

Below is my ULS log:

> Duplicate field [**Page Title**] with different values: old=[New Updated Page Title], new=[My Page Title], pageContent...

ULS containts the `xml` structure of the `pageContent` with all the fields and I see duplicate entry of the same field as below:

```
<mso:Page_x0020_Title msdt:dt="string">New Updated Page Title</mso:Page_x0020_Title>
<mso:Page_x0020_Title msdt:dt="string">My Page Title</mso:Page_x0020_Title>
```

I think, due to this double entry it is always updating the last field value as a updated value.

But I am not sure why this is happening for some of fields only.

Anyone encountered such error before?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to find the relevant custom page title property using Powershell and update the value using Powershell as an alternative.

Ex:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb("http://myweburl")
$spFile = $spWeb.GetFile("http://myweburl/Pages/mypage.aspx")
$spFile.Properties
```

this will display all the properties available for this page.Usually the default page title property name is "vti_title". I assume custom page title property would have a different name.

Then use Powershell to update the property value.

Ex

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb("http://myweburl")
$spFile = $spWeb.GetFile("http://myweburl/Pages/mypage.aspx")
$spFile.CheckOut("checkout using powershell",$null)
$spFile.Properties["customepagetitle"]="New Title"
$spFile.Update()
$spFile.CheckIn("Updated page title via PowerShell",[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
$spFile.Approve("Approved using poershell");
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution but I wanted this issue to be solved without any alternative solution.